# Maximum interval for every initial condition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, solution-verification

Consider the IVP given by:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{x^3}{1-t},\; x(0)=x_{0}$

WITHOUT solving the equation, show that:

a) For every $x_{0}$, the maximal interval is [0,1)

b) $\underset{t\uparrow 1} {\lim}\;x(t)$ exists and calculate it's value

My attempt: I know that for item a I need to show that f is continuous on the interval $[0,1)$, but do I need to show that it's locally lipschitz for every $x_{0}$?

Comment: You mean the maximal interval in $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann  Yes, we are considering only the right maximal intervals

Comment: The statement is false though. Take $x_0 > 0$. The solution is
$$\int_{x_0}^x \frac {d\tau} {\tau^3} = \int_0^t \frac {d\tau} {1 - \tau}, \\
\frac 1 {2 x_0^2} - \frac 1 {2 x^2} = -\ln(1 - t) \land x > 0.$$
$-\ln(1 - t)$ changes from $0$ to $\infty$ and thus takes the value $1/(2 x_0^2)$ at some $t_0 \in (0, 1)$. Then $x(t_0) = \infty$.

Comment: Did you miss a minus sign in the right side? Else the comment by Maxim shows that the task is impossible.

Comment: I did miss a minus sign, I apologize, hopefully now the question does have a solution

Comment: a) seems a bit misleading to me, the constituent equation is not defined for $t=1$, so $t=1$ certainly imposes a hard limit.

Comment: Now you see that as the vector field points inwards towards zero, all solutions are bounded by their initial value, and thus defined as far as the domain reaches. Because of the singularity at $t=1$, there is enough velocity that the limit zero is reached, independent of the initial point. Were there any related theorems or examples for similar tasks ("without solving the equation") discussed in your course?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both of these questions is contained in the proof in Appendix D.$6$ of a more general [result](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387217529). The limit in part $b)$ is zero.

I can offer a partial proof from scratch, not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.  I think it is labored, though, so I would like to see a better, complete one.

If $r>0$ and $0<a<1$ then, $|f(t,x)|\le \frac{(r+x_0)^3}{1-a}$ on $\overline B(x_0,r)$ and for all $t\in [0,a)$, and 
$$
|f(t,x)-f(t,x')|=\left(\frac{x^2+xx'+x'^2}{1-t}\right)\cdot |x-x'|\le \frac{3(r+x_0)^2)}{1-a}\cdot |x-x'|.
$$ 
Now apply the Picard–Lindelöf theorem: there is a unique solution at least for times in the interval $\left[0,\min\left\{a,\frac{r(1-a)}{(r+x_0)^3}\right\}\right)$. To conclude, we would like to show that there is an $r$ for which 
$$
a\le\frac{r(1-a)}{(r+x_0)^3}
$$ 
but unfortunately, the lone maximum of the functions $r\mapsto \frac{r(1-a)}{(r+x_0)^3}$ depends heavily on $x_0.$

For part $b).$ note that if $x_0=0$ then the trivial solution works. Otherwise, take the case $x_0>0$. The other case $x_0<0$ should be similar. Then, $x$ is decreasing at $t=0.$ If $x(\tau)<0$ for some $0<\tau<1,$ then $x$ is increasing at $\tau$, which implies that

1. there is a $\tau_1$ such that $0<\tau_1<\tau$ and $x(\tau_1)<x(\tau)$

and

2. $x$ has a local minimum $\tau_2$ on $(0,\tau_1)$ that satisfies $x(\tau_2)<x(\tau_1)<x(\tau)<0.$

But this would imply that $x'(\tau_2)>0$ which is a contradiction.

We conclude that $x$ is nonegative on $[0,1)$, and this implies also that $x$ is nonincreasing there. Therefore, if there is a $\tau\in (0,1)$ such that $x(\tau)=0$ then $x(t)=0$ for all $\tau<t<1$ and we may conclude that $\underset{t\to 1^-}\lim x(t)=0.$

In any case, the limit exists because $x$ is monotone and bounded. and $\underset{t\to 1^-}\lim x(t)=l\ge 0$ and it remains to show that $l=0.$

Comment: How did get that x is bounded on [0,1)?

Comment: $x(0)=x_0>0$ by hypothesis and $x$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing on $[0,1)$.