# Proving the solution of the IVP is positive for all $t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d t}=-\frac{x^3}{1-t} \quad x(0)=x_0>0
\end{equation}

How can I show that $x(t)>0$ for $t \in\left[0, \alpha\right)$, where $\alpha \leq 1$?

I have some ideas, but have not been able to use them to write/reach a proper conclusion. We can study the sign of $\frac{d x}{d t}$ to conclude that it is negative in the interval $\left[0, \alpha\right)$, thus implying that $x(t)$ should be decreasing in the same interval.

Moreover, from the initial condition, we know that $x(t)$ must be positive in a neighborhood of $x_{0}$. How can I combine these facts together with the theorem of existence and uniqueness to show that $x(t)$ can never reach zero nor attain negative values?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: Since $x$ is continuous and $x_0>0$, there is a $\alpha >0$ s.t. $x(t)>0$ for all $t\in [0,\alpha )$...

Comment: If $x(t_1) = 0$ then both $x$ and the zero function are solutions of the same IVP...

Comment: @MartinR But the zero function does not satisfy the IVP, since the initial condition is positive, or am I missing something?

Comment: They are both solutions of the differential equation with the initial value $x(t_1) = 0$, therefore they must coincide everywhere on their domain. This is a standard argument: If a constanct function $x(t) = c$ solves the DE then every other solution can not take the value $c$.

Comment: Interesting @MartinR, got it! So $x(t)$ cannot attain negative values because it cannot cross the x axis?

Comment: @Gonçalo because it can be hard enough so that even though you would not be able to solve such an ode, you would be able to still evaluate such behaviour

Comment: That is true @Gonçalo

Comment: @MartinR when you mentioned that both x and the zero function does not satisfy the IVP, are you referring to the explicit solution x? Because otherwise I cannot see why x must be different from zero since i have not calculated an explicit solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this because I saw a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580226/maximum-interval-for-every-initial-condition?noredirect=1) with an answer that I think isn't helpful to the OP here.

---

One can actually solve the ODE in question because one can write $$
\frac{dx}{dt} =-\frac{x^3}{1-t} \implies \frac{dx}{x^3} = -\frac{dt}{1-t} \implies \int -\frac{dx}{x^3} = \int \frac{dt}{1-t} \implies \frac{x^{-2}}{2} = -\ln(1-t) + C
$$
where $C = \frac{x_0^{-2}}{2}$. This already makes it clear that $x$ is positive on $[0,1)$, in fact $\lim_{t \to 1^-} x(t) = 0$.

Let's say, however, that we were *not* allowed to solve this equation (besides, the solve above is unrigorous, very much).

---

In that case, you must make use of "backward" uniqueness. The idea is the following : suppose that $x(t)$ meets $0$ at some point $\alpha$. The point is that we should be able to retrieve the behavior of $x$ from the fact that $x(\alpha)=0$ and that $x$ satisfies that particular differential equation. How? By running the differential equation "backwards" , namely "starting" at $\alpha$ and running time backwards to get all those values of $x$ starting from $\alpha$ all the way up to $0$. This will be given by a different differential equation, but that will also have uniqueness, and hopefully $0$ will be a solution!

Let's see : suppose that $x(t)$ satisfies $x(0)=x_0, x(\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$, and $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{x^3}{1-t}$. Consider the function $y(t) = x(\alpha-t)$. Then, differentiating, $$y'(t) = -x'(\alpha-t) = \frac{x^3(\alpha-t)}{1-(\alpha-t)} = \frac{y^3(t)}{1-\alpha+t}$$ for all $t \in (0,\alpha)$, and $y(0)=0$. We also have $y(\alpha) = x_0 > 0$.

Does the differential equation $$
y' = \frac{y^3}{1-\alpha+t}
$$
have a unique solution in the domain $[0,\alpha]$? Sure, it does have a solution which is $y \equiv 0$.

Observe that if $y$ is any solution to this differential equation starting from $y(0)=0$ then on the interval $[0,\alpha]$, if $y(x)>0$ then $y>0$, and hence $y'>0$ : that is, $y$ is increasing with respect to $t$. We already know that $y(0)=0$ and $y(\alpha) = x_0$. Therefore, any solution $y$ for time $t \in [0,\alpha]$, satisfies $y \in [0,x_0]$.

Now uniqueness follows from the Lipschitz continuity implied by the boundedness of partial derivatives of the right hand side $f(y,t) = \frac{y^3}{1-t}$ on the domain $[0,x_0] \times [0,\alpha]$ : $$\frac{3x_0^2}{1-\alpha}>\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{3y^2}{1-t} > 0$$
and $$
0> \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -\frac{y^3}{(1-t)^2} > -\frac{x_0^3}{(1-\alpha)^2}
$$
on the interval $(y,t) \in [0,x_0] \times [0,1-\alpha]$. Since Lipschitz continuity of the right hand side implies uniqueness, it follows that $y(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,\alpha]$. This is equivalent to $x(\alpha - t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,\alpha]$, the same as saying that $x(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,\alpha]$. That's a contradiction as $x(0)=x_0>0$.

Consequently, no such $\alpha$ exists. As the explicit solution shows, $\lim_{t \to 1^-} x(t) = 0$. The reason why the above argument fails at $1$ is, if you notice, the backward uniqueness *fails* at the time $1$. Write that particular $y(t) =x(1-t)$ and ask it to satisfy the same DE with $y(0)=0$ and you suddenly *can* have two different solutions. That's why $\alpha<1$ is necessary for this argument to work.

Comment: That was amazing. Do you have further references on problems and/or any material covering this same specific idea of backward uniqueness and its uses?

Comment: Also, why does $y \in\left[0, x_0\right]$?

Comment: @Lucas For the first, I don't really know of a textbook covering it, but I do know that backward uniqueness is apparently an interesting phenomena in itself, say for the heat equation, and in general it applies in this kind of a problem. For the second part, I made the necessary edits.